# Protocol requirement of the type "class", but want it to be flexible between what property of the class

Tags: swift, class, struct, protocols

I am making a conversion script for an app I am making and would like to make a protocol for all of the different conversion structs I make. I want all of them to have a property named `unitType`, a property named `amount`, and a mutating function named `convert(to otherType) -> Double`. Here is the code:

```swift
public class Units {
    enum TemperatureUnits {
        case fahrenheit, rankine
        case celsius, kelvin
    }
    enum DistanceUnits {
        case inch, foot, yard, mile
        case millimeter, centimeter, meter, kilometer
    }
    //Plus any others I decide to do
}

//Want to create a protocol here
protocol Conversion {
    var unitType
    var amount: Double 
    func convert(to otherType) -> Double
}

//This struct works, but i want to implement the protocol
public struct Temperature {

    var unitType: Units.TemperatureUnits
    var amount: Double
    
    mutating func convert(to otherType: Units.TemperatureUnits) -> Double {
        
        var returnAmount: Double
        
        switch otherType {
            
        case .fahrenheit:
            switch unitType {
                
            case .fahrenheit:
              returnAmount = amount
            case .celsius:
              returnAmount = (amount * (9/5)) + 32
            case .kelvin:
              returnAmount = (amount - 273.15) * (9/5) + 32
            case .rankine:
              returnAmount = amount - 459.67
            }
        case .celsius:
            switch unitType {
                
            case .celsius:
              returnAmount = amount
            case .kelvin:
              returnAmount = amount - 273.15
            case .fahrenheit:
              returnAmount = (amount - 32) * (5/9)
            case .rankine:
              returnAmount = (amount - 491.67) * (5/9)
            }
        case .kelvin:
            switch unitType {
                
            case .fahrenheit:
              returnAmount = (amount - 32) * (5/9) + 273.15
            case .celsius:
              returnAmount = amount + 273.15
            case .kelvin:
              returnAmount = amount
            case .rankine:
              returnAmount = amount * (5/9)
            }
        case .rankine:
            switch unitType {
                
            case .rankine:
              returnAmount = amount
            case .fahrenheit:
              returnAmount = amount + 459.67
            case .celsius:
              returnAmount = (amount * (9/5)) + 491.67
            case .kelvin:
              returnAmount = amount * (9/5)
            }
        }
        
        unitType = otherType
        amount = returnAmount
        return returnAmount
    }
}
```

Now, like I said, the problem comes when I try to make a protocol that multiple of these structs can conform to. The whole reason I encased the enums in a `Units` class was to keep them organized, and to see if I could make the protocol work like this:

```swift
protocol Conversion {
    var unitType: Units { get set }
    var amount: Double { get set }
    func convert(to otherType: Units) -> Double
}
```

and then implement it like this:

```swift
public struct Temperature: Conversion {
    var unitType: Units.TemperatureUnits
    var amount: Double

    mutating func convert(to otherType: Units.TemperatureUnits) -> Double {
        //code
    }
}

public struct Distance: Conversion {
    var unitType: Units.DistanceUnits
    var amount: Double

    mutating func convert(to otherType: Units.DistanceUnits) -> Double {
        //code
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. I am wondering if I am able to create a protocol with this type of flexibility in swift, or if creating a protocol in this situation is even necessary. (Also, the nested switch statements were the most efficient way I could find to apply the conversions - I am sure there is a more efficient way but I just couldn't figure it out.)

Comment: Don't reinvent this. Have a look at the documentation for [Units and Measurement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/units_and_measurement).

Comment: Use Measurement you can add any custom units with a few lines of code.

Comment: Thank you, this makes it a-lot easier. But I was mostly doing this project to grow my swift comfortability, I would still like to know if there is a way to do the thing with the protocol if it’s not too much of a hassle.

Comment: Also, now reading up on the docs , I find it interesting how the way I set up the data structure is astonishingly similar to the way they set it up. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it with generics. Even though I tried it before posting this question, I wasn't using it correctly.

```swift
protocol Conversion {
    associatedtype T
    
    var unitType: T { get set }
    var amount: Double { get set }
    mutating func convert(to otherType: T) -> Double
}
```

Also thank you for the people who pointed me towards the Units and Measurement API Collection. You saved me a lot of time.